# Nominal value of shares

Tags: financial-literacy, stock-analysis, shares

If I hold shares that are quoted as

```
"Company XYZ Euro 0.01"
```

But the stock exchange listing is for

```
"Company XYZ Euro 0.0002"
```

(In both cases the numbers are part of the stock name - the price is in a different column).

What does that mean? Are my shares are valued 50x higher than the stock exchange listing?

Comment: It could be the bid/ask spread.  You could buy it for 0.01 now but could only sell it for 0.0002.

Comment: Neither of the numbers are the stock price. They are all part of the name of the stock. Edited to clarify

Comment: Can you link the to actual example or show a screenshot?

Comment: Here is the MSX link http://www.bolsamadrid.es/ing/aspx/Empresas/FichaValor.aspx?ISIN=ES0105200002&ClvEmis=05200 which shows nominal value at 0.0002 but the shares in my account are listed as I say above, Abengoa Class B Euro 0.01

Comment: Is it perhaps the par value the shares where issued at? Or are you trading penny stocks?

Comment: Alas, I wasn't when I bought them! ;-)

Comment: What do you mean by par value? @Keith?

Answer (score 3):

They are 2 different [class of shares belonging to the same company](http://www.abengoa.com/web/en/accionistas_y_gobierno_corporativo/estructura_capital/). Class A shares [par value of 0.01] have 100 voting rights per share. Class B shares [par value of 0.0002] have one voting rights.

Both are listed separately with different ISN and trade at slightly different values. The [Class A](http://www.bolsamadrid.es/ing/aspx/Empresas/FichaValor.aspx?ISIN=ES0105200416) at higher value than [Class B](http://www.bolsamadrid.es/ing/aspx/Empresas/FichaValor.aspx?ISIN=ES0105200002) which looks right as it has more voting power.

Comment: The share listed in my account is ABENGOA SA EUR 0.01 CLASS B, which is neither of the above, and not listed separately. How can I tell the price for it? Or do I just have a class B share which for some reason is listed as nominal 0.01 and if so why?

Comment: @SideshowBob You would need to check with you broker. Even an ISIN check can indicate exactly what you have.